Long inclusion symbol
With \joinrel{=}{=} we can produce a longer equality sign. How can we produce a longer inclusion symbol? Obviously \joinrel{\subset}{\subset} isn't going to cut it.

You are using \joinrel wrong.

\joinrel is just a shorthand for inserting some negative space, which is useful since it cancels out exactly the spaces added between two \mathrel objects. To join two equal signs you should have =\jointrel= and not \joinrel{=}{=}. (Try it yourself!)

But you are unlikely to make this work with \subset, since to make a longer version you would need to joint \subset to a symbol that is two parallel horizontal lines that are vertically spaced apart the same amount as the opening to \subset; my go to fonts certainly don't have such a symbol. You can probably fake it using rules though.

You could use \scalebox to stretch a character horizontally, but then vertical portions become thick. So you could use trimclip to isolate the middle of a character and stretch it horizontally. The macro \midstretch takes 4 arguments, so for example, \midstretch{$\subset$}{.5}{.8}{4} will take the character \subset and stretch from the 50% point to the 80% point (horizontally) by a factor of 4.

Works with anything that has a reasonably horizontal(ish) portion
\midstretch{$\cup$}{.48}{.52}{6}\midstretch{$\cap$}{.48}{.52}{6}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, trimclip, calc}

\newcommand{\midstretch}[4]{%
    \clipbox*{0pt {-1ex} {#2\width} {1.1\height}}{#1}%
    \scalebox{#4}[1]{\clipbox{{#2\width} -1ex  {\width-#3\width} -1pt}{#1}}%
    \clipbox*{{#3\width} -1ex {\width} {1.1\height}}{#1}%
    }

\begin{document}

\midstretch{$\subset$}{.5}{.8}{4}
\midstretch{$\subseteq$}{.5}{.8}{4}

\end{document}


Is it possible to force the long-inclusion to have the same vertical height as \subset?

You can append two copies of half the symbol (clipped at the left).
No need to do guesses about the dimensions of the symbols. This should work with any math font set (unless it has very peculiar symbols for set inclusion). The “negative clipping” is a safety measure against the symbols protrude from their bounding box at top or bottom.
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{newtx}
\usepackage{trimclip}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\longsubset}{}{\longsub@\subset}
\NewDocumentCommand{\longsubseteq}{}{\longsub@\subseteq}
\NewDocumentCommand{\longsupset}{}{\longsup@\supset}
\NewDocumentCommand{\longsupseteq}{}{\longsup@\supseteq}

\newcommand{\longsub@}[1]{%
  #1%
  \joinrel\mathrel{\mathpalette\longsub@@{#1}}%
  \joinrel\mathrel{\mathpalette\longsub@@{#1}}%
}
\newcommand{\longsub@@}[2]{%
  \smash{\clipbox{{0.5\width} -2 0 -2}{$\m@th#1#2$}}%
}

\newcommand{\longsup@}[1]{%
  \mathrel{\mathpalette\longsup@@{#1}}\joinrel
  \mathrel{\mathpalette\longsup@@{#1}}\joinrel
  #1%
}
\newcommand{\longsup@@}[2]{%
  \smash{\clipbox{0 -2 {0.5\width} -2}{$\m@th#1#2$}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A\subset B\subseteq C$

$A\longsubset B\longsubseteq C$

$\scriptstyle A\subset B\subseteq C$

$\scriptstyle A\longsubset B\longsubseteq C$

$A\supset B\supseteq C$

$A\longsupset B\longsupseteq C$

$\scriptstyle A\supset B\supseteq C$

$\scriptstyle A\longsupset B\longsupseteq C$

\end{document}


If I uncomment \usepackage{newtx}, the output is


You can fake it by creating a symbol that is like the equals sign, but with the two lines spread further apart. This can be accomplished by just drawing some rules. But note that this relies on a lot of fine-tuning by hand (which will change based on the font used and you would want to create appropriate versions at the different math style (\displaystyle and \scriptstyle etc.)
I give just a simple proof of concept below:
\documentclass{article}
%% With a lot of fine tuning by hand
\newcommand\fakeeq{\mathrel{\rlap{\rule[-0.4pt]{0.7em}{0.4pt}}\rule[5pt]{0.7em}{0.4pt}}}

\begin{document}
$=\joinrel=$ $\subset\joinrel\fakeeq$
\end{document}


If you really zoom in and squint you can see that what I did still wasn't a perfect match. But it is close enough that at usual zoom level this shouldn't be noticeable.
